# GCP Nodejs Flex env node.js installation failure with wrong signature

Tags: google-app-engine, gitlab-ci

Developing nodejs & angular app, using Gitlab to store code and using GL CI/CD to deploy current version of app on GCP. Approximate a month ago started to get error during node.js installation:

```
Step #1: INFO[0028] RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=12'
Step #1: INFO[0028] cmd: /bin/sh
Step #1: INFO[0028] args: [-c /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=12'] 
Step #1: % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current 
Step #1: Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 
Step #1: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 100 32.1M 100 32.1M 0 0 47.5M 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 47.5M 
Step #1: % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current 
Step #1: Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 
Step #1: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 100 3838 100 3838 0 0 21107 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21204 
Step #1: gpg: Signature made Thu Sep 10 15:04:50 2020 UTC using RSA key ID C17AB93C gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found 
Step #1: The Node.js binary could not be verified. 
Step #1: This means it may not be an officially released Node.js binary 
Step #1: or may have been tampered with.
```

I thought that it's issue with GL & Google accounts, created project from scratch (both GL & GAE), but got no luck.

My gitlab-ci.yml script section

```
- echo $GCP_SERVICE_KEY > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
- gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
- gcloud --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID app deploy app.yaml dispatch.yaml
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 4

env_variables:
  CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: gs://[projectname]-deploy
```

Could anyone help me to solve this error or point where to find steps to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to add app.yaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who facing same issue - remove engine section from package.json, because it possibly frustrate GCP installer.

Comment: if you are using a flex environment removing the engine section from package.json is the only option that works. thanks @kirill-k

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/issues/214

Its seems like the issue is with node 14.10

Comment: not only with 14.10. I tried to deploy with >=12 node engine version, faced same issue. Once I've removed this section from package.json - it was successfully deployed.